# How to make LAUNCHER activity be started instead of activity on top of activity stack after process is killed by OS?

Tags: android-activity, stack

Hi I have looked for this question and can’t find it, so here goes...

My application starts with a sign in activity which logs the user in. Upon successful authentication, the initial launcher activity is replaced by a ‘content’ activity.

Everything works fine until I place the app in the background via the home button and start up some memory consuming applications.

Upon returning to my app, Android tries to recreate the activity on the top of the activity stack, however what I’d like  is to have the signin activity be restarted instead.

The reason being that the user needs to be reauthenticated again due to inactivity in communicating with the server.

Is there a way of specifying this behavior in the Manifest.xml file or programmatically?

I’m aware of save/restore activity state, but in this case I want the app to restart with the signin activity, thus bypassing needless restore. (Since the user will have to be signed in again due to inactivity)

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE:The issue arises solely when my application process is killed by Android to reclaim memory to be used by other apps that are being loaded.  The only aspect of my app that still exists at that point is the activity stack and its top entry is my MainActivity.  This is because the activity stack is NOT inside the app process.

So Android is attempting to be nice to the user and it tries to restore the state of my MainActivity. However my ability to authenticate against my server is gone at that point because the user’s credentials have been wiped from memory together with anything that used memory.

Therefore instead of attempting to restore my MainActivity under these conditions, I’d like my app to start at the activity which is designated as the LAUNCHER activity in the Manifest.xml file. This activity implements the signin process which gets credentials from the user and sets up various singletons whih are not tied to any specific activity.  NOTE: I don’t want to persist credentials or cookies for various reasons, so that is not an option.

Comment: A few options come to mind. 1. Either you implement the onResume() method of the Activity that’s going to be recreated so that it calls the sign-in activity instead (this will prove a bit tedious). 2. Implement the onPause() or onStop() methods so that when the activity is is leaving the foreground, it quits. That way, upon next launch, the sign-in activity displays.

Comment: I don’t want it to always start with the sign-in activity, only when my process has been killed by the OS. I can detect this situation just not sure about the cleanest way of doing this.

Comment: Then am really not getting what you want to achieve.

Comment: The issue arises solely when my application process is killed by Android to reclaim memory to be used by other apps that are being loaded.